# Radgrid blank column space between grid and vertical scroll bar

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am using a RadGrid with four frozen columns, when I bind the grid, it shows (Chrome) an empty column on the right end, and all the data are misaligned one row to the right. In IE it is totally messed up!

```
<ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="false" EnableRowHoverStyle="false" AllowDragToGroup="false" >
<Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" ScrollHeight="350px" FrozenColumnsCount="4">
</Scrolling>
<ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
  <Resizing AllowColumnResize="false" EnableRealTimeResize="true" />
</ClientSettings>
```

Function:

```
function GridCreated(sender, args)
 {
  var scrollArea = sender.GridDataDiv;
  var dataHeight = sender.get_masterTableView().get_element().clientHeight;
  if (dataHeight < 350)
  { 
    scrollArea.style.height = dataHeight + 47 + "px";
  } 
}
```

Comment: <ClientSettings AllowColumnsReorder="false" EnableRowHoverStyle="false" AllowDragToGroup="false" >
               <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" ScrollHeight="350px" FrozenColumnsCount="4"></Scrolling>
               <ClientEvents OnGridCreated="GridCreated" />
               <Resizing AllowColumnResize="false" EnableRealTimeResize="true" />
          </ClientSettings>

Comment: function GridCreated(sender, args) {
        var scrollArea = sender.GridDataDiv;
        var dataHeight = sender.get_masterTableView().get_element().clientHeight;

        if (dataHeight < 350) {
            scrollArea.style.height = dataHeight + 47 + "px";
        }
    }

Comment: Which is the scope of the code in your comments. If you need to update the code do it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the scrolling height as following on the HTML side:

```
<Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" ScrollHeight="" FrozenColumnsCount="4">
</Scrolling>
```

Let us know if it works.